# omnigraffle Keyboard shortcuts missing

Tags: keyboard, system-settings, omnigraffle

[image]

I have been trying to adjust the keyboard shortcuts for omnigraffle and for some reason they are completely gone. I am really not sure how this happened but I can not get my zoom keys to work. This is driving me nuts. Any ideas how to fix this?

The docs at omnigraffle show they should be there.  Help?

Comment: assuming you did not have the 14 days trial version? if not can you add it again using the + sign?

Comment: @Buscar How would the trial version of OmniGraffle affect this?

Comment: I have the full version.  I just heard from Omnigraffle https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/keyboard-shortcuts-missing/6295 they are located somewhere else.  They cmd+> keys do not work. :( Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/keyboard-shortcuts-missing/6295/2...

> Try using ⇧⌘< and ⇧⌘>. Some, but not all, keyboards require the use of the shift key to get the greater-than and less-than symbols.